# OpenCV: Error copying one image to another

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, runtime-error, pixel

I am trying to copy one image to another pixel by pixel (I know there are sophisticated methods available. I am trying to solve another problem and answer to this will be useful).

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat Img;
    Img = imread("../../../stereo_images/left01.jpg");

    Mat copyImg = Mat::zeros(Img.size(), CV_8U);
    for(int i=0; i<Img.rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<Img.cols; j++){
            copyImg.at<uchar>(j,i) = Img.at<uchar>(j,i);
        }}
    namedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Image", Img);
    namedWindow("copyImage", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("copyImage", copyImg);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code in visual studio I get the following error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv\opencv-2.4.9\ope
ncv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537
```

I know for fact that Img's type is CV_8U. Why does this happen ?

Thanks!

Comment: Apart from the issues in you code pointed out in the answers below, using `at<>()` the way you do is really inefficient. For a better way, see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way. Also, you could have figured out the problem yourself by looking at the OpenCV source line referred to by the error message and then checking each condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know for fact that Img's type is CV_8U.

But CV_8U is just the image depth (**8**-bit **U**-nsigned). The type also specifies the number of channels, which is usually three. One for blue, one for green and one for red in this order as default for OpenCV. The type would be CV_8UC3 (**C**-hannels = **3**). `imread` will convert even a black and white image to a 3-channel image by default. `imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)` will load a 1-channel image (CV_8UC1). But if you're not sure the easiest solution is

```
Mat copyImg = Mat::zeros(Img.size(), Img.type());
```

To access the array elements you have to know the size of it. Using `.at<uchar>()` on a 3-channel image will only access the first channel because you have 3*8 bit per pixel. So on a 3-channel image you have to use

```
copyImg.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = Img.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
```

where `Vec3b` is a `cv::Vec<uchar, 3>`. You should also note that the first argument of `at<>(,)` is the index along dim 0 which are the rows and second argument cols. Or in other words in classic 2d-xy-chart order you access a pixel with `.at<>(y,x) == .at<>(Point(x,y))`.

Comment: It was a problem with no. of channels. Since the image themselves were grey, I did not realize they had three channels. Also, when I opened Img in Matlab it did not show me three channels like Img(:,:,1), (:,:,2)& (:,:,3). It just showed a matrix with 640x480 with unit8 values. Thanks for the help! I am just new to CV.

Answer (score 5):

```
// will read in a rgb image , no matter what the content is
Img = imread("../../../stereo_images/left01.jpg");
```

to make it read grayscale images use:

```
Img = imread("../../../stereo_images/left01.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

then, you don't need to copy per pixel (and you should even avoid that), just use:

```
Mat im2 = Img.clone();
```

*if* you do per-pixel loops, watch out to get the indices right. it's row-col world here, not x,y, so it should be:

```
 copyImg.at<uchar>(i,j) = Img.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

in your case

Answer (score 3):

your problem is with this line :

```
copyImg.at<uchar>(j,i) = Img.at<uchar>(j,i);
```

It should be :

```
copyImg.at<uchar>(i,j) = Img.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

Note that if you want to copy image you can simply do this :

```
Mat copyImg = Img.clone();
```